# RGB-D Handheld Mapping with RealSense R200

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, rtabmap, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following the [RGB-D Handheld Mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/HandHeldMapping)  tutorial . First I ran the following command

```
$ roslaunch realsense_camera r200_nodelet_default.launch
```

While the realsense_camera node is running, in a new tab I ran

```
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" depth_topic:=/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw
```

The RTABMAP GUI is launched as expected but there is no image.

In the terminal that I launched the RTABMAP GUI, I am receiving the following warning.

```
[ WARN] [1532462055.394145038]: /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry: Did not receive data since 5 seconds! Make sure the input topics are published ("$ rostopic hz my_topic") and the timestamps in their header are set. 
/rtabmap/rgbd_odometry subscribed to (approx sync):
   /camera/rgb/image_rect_color,
   /camera/depth/image_raw,
   /camera/rgb/camera_info
```

Same thing happens when I run

```
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" depth_topic:=/camera/depth/points/image_raw
```

Can you help me solve this issue? Thank you.

*I am running Ros Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit machine.*

**Edit**

The published topics are:

```
$ rostopic list
/camera/color/camera_info
/camera/color/image_raw
/camera/color/image_raw/compressed
/camera/color/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/color/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/color/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/color/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/color/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/color/image_raw/theora
/camera/color/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/color/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/camera_info
/camera/depth/image_raw
/camera/depth/image_raw/compressed
/camera/depth/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/depth/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/image_raw/theora
/camera/depth/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/depth/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/depth/points
/camera/driver/parameter_descriptions
/camera/driver/parameter_updates
/camera/ir/camera_info
/camera/ir/image_raw
/camera/ir/image_raw/compressed
/camera/ir/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/ir/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/ir/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/ir/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/ir/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/ir/image_raw/theora
/camera/ir/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/ir/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/ir2/camera_info
/camera/ir2/image_raw
/camera/ir2/image_raw/compressed
/camera/ir2/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/ir2/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/ir2/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/ir2/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/ir2/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/ir2/image_raw/theora
/camera/ir2/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/ir2/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/camera/nodelet_manager/bond
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
/tf_static
```

I think the RTABMAP GUI is not looking for the right topic; there is nothing matching "/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw". What should I change the

```
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" depth_topic:=/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw
```

command with?

**Edit 2**

As Martin suggested, I tried running

```
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" depth_topic:=/camera/depth/image_raw
```

Again, there's no image in the GUI. I also ran "rostopic hz /camera/depth/image_raw" and got:

```
$ rostopic hz /camera/depth/image_raw
subscribed to [/camera/depth/image_raw]
average rate: 60.027
    min: 0.016s max: 0.017s std dev: 0.00024s window: 57
average rate: 60.022
    min: 0.016s max: 0.017s std dev: 0.00025s window: 117
average rate: 60.018
    min: 0.016s max: 0.017s std dev: 0.00025s window: 177
average rate: 60.015
    min: 0.016s max: 0.017s std dev: 0.00025s window: 237
average rate: 60.007
    min: 0.016s max: 0.017s std dev: 0.00025s window: 297
average rate: 60.002
    min: 0.016s max: 0.017s std dev: 0.00024s window: 357
average rate: 60.003
    min: 0.016s max: 0.017s std dev: 0.00024s window: 417
average rate: 60.004
    min: 0.016s max: 0.017s std dev: 0.00023s window: 477
average rate: 60.005
    min: 0.016s max: 0.017s std dev: 0.00024s window: 538
average rate: 60.005
    min: 0.016s max: 0.017s std dev: 0.00024s window: 598
```

This shows that we are receiving something from this topic. I also ran

Run the following command

```
$ rqt_image_view
```

just to check if the camera is working and it is indeed working:

https://ibb.co/fWS8ET

Please notice that the chosen topic is "/camera/depth/image_raw".

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298338/rgb-d-handheld-mapping-with-realsense-r200/) by [csg](https://answers.ros.org/users/36089/csg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-07-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2018-07-24**:
Looks like first we need to check what the topic is. "rostopic list" should display it, afterwards try "rostopic echo --noarr " to see if you get some data.

**Comment by [csg](https://answers.ros.org/users/36089/csg/) on 2018-07-24**:
Hello @Humpelstilzchen can you check my edit? Thank you.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2018-07-24**:
Which `realsense_camera` package version do you have? Just tried with latest version of their [indigo-devel](https://github.com/intel-ros/realsense/tree/indigo-devel) branch and `/camera/depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw` should be published by `realsense_camera` node.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2018-07-24**:
Just found the difference, try `roslaunch realsense_camera r200_nodelet_rgbd.launch` instead like in the tutorial.

**Comment by [csg](https://answers.ros.org/users/36089/csg/) on 2018-07-24**:
@matlabbe This one worked. Thank you very much!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-24**:
Can you please attach your images directly to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From all the topics you listed, `/camera/depth/image_raw` looks like it's the only candidate. First make sure that you're receiving something on that topic:

```
rostopic hz /camera/depth/image_raw
```

Then change your command to:

```
$ roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" depth_topic:=/camera/depth/image_raw
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2018-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [csg](https://answers.ros.org/users/36089/csg/) on 2018-07-24**:
Hello @MartinGünther please check out my **Edit 2**, thank you.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2018-07-24**:
Just for somebody stumbling on this later: The comment by @matlabbe solved this problem.